# Spark Master vs Yarn Resource manager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How does yarn allocate resources for spark applications and how it is done when spark runs in standalone mode?

Answer (score 0):

You define the driver memory size, deployment mode, number of executors and their memory sizes when you run `spark-submit`. If no options are provided, the defaults from `spark-env` and/or `yarn-site.xml` are used. Then that amount of resources will be scheduled.

If dynamic executor execution is enabled, and you're reading data from HDFS, for example, then more or less executors may start, depending on how many file blocks the data contains